# Unable to Change at Highest resolution

Tags: display-resolution

I am currently using ubuntu 23.04 release in my Mi Notebook Pro having highest resolution of 2560*1600.But it is default on lower resolution.Even settings shows 2560*1600 but it's not,Screen looks little bit blurry,details missing.I tried adding custom resolution in terminal and Adding resolution in .config files.But it's not working in my laptop.Tell me any other solution to fix this.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Can you please clarify _what_ `.config` files you edited? Please be as specific as possible about what you tried, as that will help in troubleshooting your issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today, it took me a while to fix so as soon as I did I came in here to check if anyone was having the same issue.

For some reason when I turned on my computer today the resolution was lower than usual. You said that your settings show the highest resolution however mine did not, so I am not sure if the problem is the same.

I fixed it by updating NVIDIA drivers running these commands, maybe give it a try.

sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo reboot